# How to join images to array and show them in the slider in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6

I am working Angular project and I have added the ngx editor in which I have added the images and the text. I have separated the images from the string coming from the database and I want to show them in the slider.

This is my **blog.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../_services';
import { User } from '../_models/user'
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { AuthenticationServiceService } from '../_services';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog',
  templateUrl: './blog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog.component.css']
})
export class BlogComponent implements OnInit {
  usersBlog: User[] = [];
  msg: string = null;
  m: any = [];
  src: any = [];
  public imagesUrl;

  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationServiceService,
    private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.getBlog();

    for (var imsgeSrc in this.src) {
    this.imagesUrl = this.usersBlog[imsgeSrc];
     console.log("fhfhfh:",this.imagesUrl);
    }

  }

  getBlog() {
    this.userService.getBlog().pipe(first()).subscribe(usersBlog => {
      this.usersBlog = usersBlog;

      for (var i in this.usersBlog) {

        var patt1 = /<img(.*?)>/g;
        this.m = String(this.usersBlog[i].blog).match(patt1);
        for (var k in this.m) {
          this.src = $(this.m[k]).attr('src');
          console.log('imsg:', this.src); <!-- I am fetching the src of the images. -->
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

In this code, I have separated the src of the images but the problem is that, It is not showing to the slider because I am not able to join them as a array.

This is my **blog.component.html**:

```
<angular-image-slider [images]="imagesUrl"></angular-image-slider>
```

It is not showing the images in the slider because it is not getting the `imagesUrl`.

This is result of: `console.log('imsg:', this.src);`

[image]

But the problem is that, I am not able to set the images as an array and show them to the html:

```
 ngOnInit() {

    this.getBlog();

    for (var imsgeSrc in this.src) {
    this.imagesUrl = this.usersBlog[imsgeSrc];
     console.log("fhfhfh:",this.imagesUrl);
    }

  }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale. Sorry, I don't have the stackblitz for this.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale. I have updated my code and I only have to make the array of images showing differently. So, Can you please help?

Comment: Do you need an array which contains all the `this.src` in it, inside a forloop?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale. ngOnInit() {}, In this, I an trying to do this and pass the array to the html.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale. I have also showed the result of the images in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store image URL inside for loop then you can declare one array and add an item into it like:

`blog.component.ts:`

```
images: any[] = []; // array like this

getBlog() {
    this.userService.getBlog().pipe(first()).subscribe(usersBlog => {
      this.usersBlog = usersBlog;
      for (var i in this.usersBlog) {
        var patt1 = /<img(.*?)>/g;
        this.m = String(this.usersBlog[i].blog).match(patt1);
        for (var k in this.m) {
          var src = $(this.m[k]).attr('src');
          this.images.push(src) // Here add image url in array
        }
        console.log(this.images) /// your all images to pass as an array
      }
    });
}
```

And for HTML part:

```
<div *ngFor="let url of images">
  <angular-image-slider [images]="url"></angular-image-slider>
</div>
```

Comment: If I want to show images for the particular blog only.

Comment: Your answer is correct but It is joining all the blog images. if I want to join for the particular blog only.

Comment: So, Can you please help?

Comment: unable to understand? What you mean by particular blog?

Comment: this.usersBlog, shows all the blogs and this.usersBlog[i].blog contains all blogs data. Showing in the loop.

Comment: So, If I want to join the images only for the particular blog.

Comment: You can fetch that list using filter and then use forloop

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the answer.